# WCF service method unavailable in WCF Test Client because it uses type SampleClass

Tags: c#, wcf

I have looked for many solutions but could not find any satisfactory answer.

I have 2 classes:

```
[DataContract]
    public class SampleClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public PerformanceCounters Performance { get; set; }
    }


[DataContract]
    public class PerformanceCounters
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double ExecutionTime { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int ResultsCount { get; set; }
}
```

My OperationContract is ->

```
public SampleClass GetResult ()
        {
            return new SampleClass(); 
        }
```

On adding this to wcfTestClient , I get the this error with red cross: "WCF service method unavailable in WCF Test Client because it uses type SampleClass"

If I replace PerformanceCounters object in SampleClass with standard data types such as int, string then it works perfectly.

I have already looked around enough but still have not got any resolution.

Comment: Looks like somehow its not able to find definition of SampleClass. Also try rebuilding solution.

Comment: Add SampleClass to knownTypes.

Comment: Have tries a numerous times but still facing the same problem.

Comment: Does the wsdl file have the information of `PerformanceCounters` ? And did you try adding attribute KnownType over the class SampleClass ? [KnownType(typeof(PerformanceCounters))]